# AngularJS routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

In the following code snippet:

```
var root = "default";

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
    .when("/",          {templateUrl: "partials/prototypes.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})

    .when("/gmp-01",    {templateUrl: setroot("gmp-01/") , controller: "PageCtrl"} )
    .when("/gmp-02",    {templateUrl: setroot("gmp-02/") , controller: "PageCtrl"} )
    .when("/gmp-03",    {templateUrl: setroot("gmp-03/") , controller: "PageCtrl"} )
    .when("/gmp-04",    {templateUrl: setroot("gmp-04/") , controller: "PageCtrl"} )

    .when("/login",     {templateUrl: constructRoute("login.html") , controller: "PageCtrl"} );
}]);

function setroot(r) {
  root = r; 
  return "partials/" + root + "start-page.html";
}
```

When I run the app and navigate to "/", "setroot" is called 4 times regardless of the fact that I have not yet requested the "gmp-0x" routes. this causes the value of the root to be set to the last parameter passed in by "setroot" which in this case is "gmp-04/".

How can I make sure the value of "root" is set only when the route is requested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's executed 4 times because you're executing it 4 times. Try checking if `root` is set before overwriting it:

```
var root = null;

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
    .when("/",          {templateUrl: "partials/prototypes.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})

    .when("/gmp-01",    {templateUrl: setroot("gmp-01/") , controller: "PageCtrl"} )
    .when("/gmp-02",    {templateUrl: setroot("gmp-02/") , controller: "PageCtrl"} )
    .when("/gmp-03",    {templateUrl: setroot("gmp-03/") , controller: "PageCtrl"} )
    .when("/gmp-04",    {templateUrl: setroot("gmp-04/") , controller: "PageCtrl"} )

    .when("/login",     {templateUrl: constructRoute("login.html") , controller: "PageCtrl"} );
}]);

function setroot(r) {
  if(root === null) {
      root = r; 
  }
  return "partials/" + root + "start-page.html";
}
```

#### However

I don't think this will do what you hope it will do though, because those methods are executed when setting up the route, not when calling the route for the first time!

You might be better of setting up the templateUrl as an actual function:

```
$routeProvider.when('/gmp/:number', {
   templateUrl: function(urlattr){
       if(root === null) {
           root = urlattr.number; 
       }           
       return '/partials/gmp-' + root + 'start-page.html';
   },
   controller: 'PageCtrl'
};
```

See the difference? This is untested, but I think you get the gist.